# Regular expression match for &DaysAgo=3

Tags: php, regex

The title says it all. Just to add that the number can be multiple digits.

I'm using the following function:

```
str_replace( "/^\&DaysAgo=d+$/", "", $save_query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace()` cannot handle regular expressions. Use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for that

As you didn't showed some input data it is hard to give a full example. I'll do it if you update the question and add an example.

Answer (score 2):

Almost there: `/^&DaysAgo=\d+$/`.

You do not need to escape the ampersand in regex, but in your case, you forgot to put a slash infront of the letter `d`.

@hek2mgl's comment also applies.